# Addremove after branch merge?

Tags: command-line, merge, mercurial

I work in an environment that has a lot of development across different branches. We use mercurial as source control and often merge branches which contain other features. I am wondering if it would ever be necessary to do `hg addremove` after a branch merge and before committing?

e.g.:

```
hg checkout foo
hg merge bar
hg addremove ?
hg commit -m "MERGE: bar -> foo"
```

Is it perhaps necessary when a changeset that was pulled in added or removed a file, or is this automatically handled by mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg addremove` is usually not needed during merges. Except when you manually add or remove a file during a merge with conflices where the merge is not automatically handled.

However personally I don't recommend to use `hg addremove` anyway, especially in merge cases, as I consider it wiser to add and remove files from source control explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think you could maybe explain why I would see a list of unversioned files directly after a named branch merge?

Comment: If you merge a branch which deletes files, mercurial will happily `hg forget`them during the merge but possibly not physically remove them from the directories.

Comment: And then in this case, I could do `hg purge` ?

Comment: If you don't have any file of value (like an uncommitted patch or whatever) in your repository: sure